# How do I write this scope with nested associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have an Athlete model, which has_many Games, and each game has_many Stats. Each Stat has a sport_id, and I need to join all of the games (for a specific athlete) which have stats whose sport_id is a certain id.

Here is a visual of the database model hierarchy:

```
Athlete
    -> has_many :games
        -> has_many :stats
            -> sport_id
```

I need all the games which have a certain sport_id (determined by checking the sport_id of at least one of that game's stats), and the sport_id could be passed to the scope.

Any help? New to writing scopes, but I'm certain this can be done.

**EDIT**: I'm aware that sport_id should've been an association inside of the Game model, but I didn't build the initial product, I simply need to get this scope to work as I mentioned.

Comment: Kinda sounds like your sport id belongs in the game model rather than the stats.

Comment: scope include(:games).include(:stats).where(games: { stats: :sports_ids}} ?

Comment: @Matt you're correct, but unfortunately I'm coming into a project on the tail end of V2, and it's kinda set in stone.